# PHP get middle of text file

Tags: php, css, html

Would anyone know how to get the test inside this text file

2013-04-11^12:00|4:00|14:00

2013-07-21^10:00|15:00|18:00|15:00

2013-12-11^13:00|14:00

I want to get the values                                                                     12:00
4:00 
14:00 
10:00 etc... and forget about the rest

I tried doing this using explode() but it doesn't work and i cant use substring cause i dont know the position at all times..

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $s);
```

Comment: How about `array_slice(explode('|', $string), 1);` for each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean like:

```
    $str = "2013-04-11^12:00|4:00|14:00";
    list($year, $rest) = explode("^", $str);
    $rest_arr = explode("|", $rest);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($rest_arr);
    //gives
    Array
    (
      [0] => 12:00
      [1] => 4:00
      [2] => 14:00
    )
```

or if you want to do it from txt file:

```
//get the contents in array
$str = file("your_file.txt");
foreach($str as $val) {
    //$val is string like '2013-04-11^12:00|4:00|14:00'
    list($year, $rest) = explode("^", $val);
    $rest_arr = explode("|", $rest);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($rest_arr);
    //or echo it
    foreach($rest_arr as $time) {
        echo $time."<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: How could i print that out tho just the value... per each entry so as the text file is being read each line print out just the value ?

Comment: @user659745 the function file() gets your txt files's content into array, which we loop thru and explode to get the part you wanted, its stored in $rest_arr variable, you can do what you need with $rest_arr variable as that contains the data you want

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str = '2013-04-11^12:00|4:00|14:00';

$nstr = explode('^',$str);

$nnstr = explode('|',$nstr[1]);

$nnnstr = array_map('trim',$nnstr);    
echo '<pre>';
print_r($nnnstr);
```

Codepad Link - http://codepad.org/Kjgpgh5x